# Email (HTML) to teams channel looses color

Tags: colors, html-email, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-mail

In MSSQL, I generate and send a status mail to a team's Channel (and to my mail account). The mail looks fine in outlook, but in teams, the colors are gone.

Part of the html:

```
<td style="color:Green" align="right">44</td>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Add your own efforts such as coding approaches and docs research.

Comment: @Torben Hansen Is your sending Email from outlook? And also please share the screenshots of Email.

Comment: Based on my understanding Torben uses MS Sql to generate alert emails. It shows correctly in Outlook with colors. But it looses the color, when its moved to Microsoft teams - please confirm the same @Torben and also share the snapshots as requested above?

Answer (score 0):

We have raised a bug on this and concerned team is working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue, I resolved it by using the HEX values instead:

```
  <td style="color:#00ff00" align="right">44</td>
```